# UWP - hamburgerbutton does not show in running app

Tags: xaml, button, uwp, visual-studio-2017, designer

My problem is that i added a hamburgerbutton to my xaml code and the visual studio 2017 xamldesigner does show it. But if I run/debug the app there is no hamburgerbutton anymore. The visibility is set on true. How do I get it visible in my app ?

My xaml code:

```
<Button x:Name="HamburgerButton"  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" 
                    Width="45" Height="41" Background="LightGray" Click="HamburgerButton_Click" Margin="0,10,1225,669" Visibility="Visible" RenderTransformOrigin="1.244,3.281" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you intended to include this, but that's probably the reason why it's messed up: `RenderTransformOrigin="1.244,3.281"` and `Margin="0,10,1225,669"`. Try removing them first and check if you can see the button again. Then, I would suggest to change how you implement the positioning.

Using that kind of value for your Margin is a bad practice. This ruins the responsiveness of your application. I would suggest that you use Grid's `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` to place your control (button, in this case) somewhere.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, the margin code was the one! How can i place this button in the upper left corner using columdef und rowdef ?

Comment: If that's (upper left) the case, you can just set the HorizontalAlignment="Left" and VerticalAlignment="Top"